# Backbone template : call a method in a template from a misc javascript file

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js, marionette

In my backbone app I have multiple views/templates/models.

In some of my templates I'd like to call some function from a particular file : `favouriteManager.js`.

I know I can call function using `<% %>`. But when I try things like `<% if (favouriteManager.hasFavouriteOne()) {} %>` as expected I get an error : `favouriteManager is not defined`.

So how can I define it so that when loading the template backbone also know where to find this javascript file.

I already tried defining it in the view that uses this template but it doesn't work.

Edit: I'm using RequireJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use any module management tools like requirejs or commonjs and your `favouriteManager.js` just add `favouriteManager` variable to global context (to `window`) you just need to add script tag with it before script with view code.

**Updated:**

It you use RequireJs you can use [templateHelpers](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.view.md#viewtemplatehelpers) and attach you module to it in view. So your code will be looks like:

```
define(['marionette', 'favouriteManager', 'text!templates/myView.tpl'],
function(Marionette, favouriteManager, myViewTpl) {
  return Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: myViewTpl,
    templateHelpers: {
      favouriteManager: favouriteManager
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using RequireJS.

Comment: Doing exactly this I'm still getting a `favouriteManager is not defined `